# How to disable default English dictionary in Pspell and use only Custom dictionary?

Tags: php, pspell

I am using php and Pspell to create a custom "did you mean" feature and i need to generate suggestions strictly from the word list with me. Is there a way to turn off suggestions from default English dictionary i am using as a base. I just need pspell to look in the custom dictionary, that's it.

Comment: Hi i have answered the same question in below link. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133601/pspell-use-only-custom-dictionary

Answer (score -1):

Based on this [page](http://www.rdeeson.com/weblog/41/using-php-pspell-spell-check-functions-with-a-custom-dictionary.html):

```
$dictionary_link = pspell_new_personal("/var/dictionaries/custom_spellings","/var/dictionaries/custom_spellings");
```

Comment: @user1523595 did you read over the link I provided?  Also updated it to more closely mirror the original function.  Try doubling up your custom dictionary as it does want 2 dictionaries to use.