# Pspell use only custom dictionary

Tags: php, aspell

question like this post:
[How to disable default English dictionary in Pspell and use only Custom dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714362/how-to-disable-default-english-dictionary-in-pspell-and-use-only-custom-dictiona)

I create my custom dictionary. And test in console - all work fine. Console query like this:

```
echo Engenier | aspell -a -d /var/www/Lib/profiles.rws
```

result - only 1 suggestion. It`s correct result

But i cant repeat this result with pspell

I try this variant (http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10298706-Resolved-pspell-hell), but this doesn`t help me

All time in many variants load base "EN" dictionary with my custom. But i need only custom

How I can use only my dict?

PS: pspell - aspell for php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pspell.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi i have followed the below procedure to enable my custom dictionary only.

**Creation of custom dictionary:** 
1. Create a file called **custom.txt** in your home directory

```
touch ~/custom.txt
```

2. Add the words that you'd like to add to the dictionary, where each word is on a separate line, then run the following command

`sudo aspell --lang=en create master /usr/lib/aspell/custom.rws < ~/custom.txt`

3. To finish adding it to the dictionary change into the dictionary directory by running the following:

   `cd /usr/lib/aspell/`
4. then edit the following file:

`en.multi`

and add the following line:

```
add custom.rws
```

5 .Then the new words should be available to you in Aspell. If you want to add words to this list in future, edit the `~/custom.txt` file and run this command again:

```
sudo aspell --lang=en create master /usr/lib/aspell/custom.rws < ~/custom.txt
```

**Removing default english dictionary:**

Open `usr/lib/aspell/en.multi` file. And comment the following line

```
#add en-wo_accents.multi
```

Then the custom words only should be available to you in Aspell.

Comment: Awesome solution. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Doesn't this make the system unusable for other applications?  I want to leave the native app as is, but would like to dictate the "personal" dictionary at run time.  This looks like an all or nothing solution